# Is the product of two subharmonic function necessarily subharmonic?

Tags: calculus, harmonic-analysis, harmonic-functions

***Defin:***

A continuous function $\varphi :\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ is subharmonic if and only if, for any closed disc in $U$ with centre $\lambda_0$ and
radius $r$,$$\varphi ({\lambda _0}) \le \frac{1}{{2\pi }}\int_0^{2\pi } {\varphi ({\lambda _0} + r{e^{i\theta }})d\theta } $$

Now let $\varphi $ and $ \Gamma $ are subharmonic.

Can we say that $\varphi ({\lambda _0})\Gamma ({\lambda _0})$ is subharmonic?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Consider the subharmonic functions $|z|,-1.$

Comment: It's a big hint. Think about it for a while.